# delay transition when hovering off

Tags: css, menu, hover, delay, transition

I have two menus with hover transitions that involve the menu sliding towards the middle. I was wondering how I can delay the transition back to its original spot when hovering off? Essentially, I would like to keep it in its hovered states for a couple of seconds after hovering off.

website: http://chemipharmaceutical.com/wp/

Here is my menu css:

```
#nav_menu-2, #nav_menu-4 {
  padding-left:0;
  padding-right:0;
}
#nav_menu-2 li:hover{
  padding-right:80px;
}
#nav_menu-4 li:hover {
  padding-left:80px;
}
.sub-menu li:hover{
  padding-right:0 !important;
}
.sub-menu {
  position:absolute;
  background: rgba(31, 92, 139);
  background: rgba(31, 92, 139, .8);
  text-align:left;
  margin-top: -34px !important;
  right:20% !important;
  z-index: 9999999;
  display:none;
}
.widget .sub-menu {
  padding-left: 0;
}
.widget {
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-top: 0;
}
.widget a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.widget .menu a:link {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.widget li {
   font-size:1.7rem !important;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s !important; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation-delay: 0s !important;
  transition: all 1s linear; 
  -webkit-transition: all 1s linear; 
}
.widget li:hover {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #11334c;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 5s !important; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation-delay: 5s !important;
  transition: all 1s linear; /* delays for 1 second */
  -webkit-transition: all 1s linear; /* for Safari & Chrome */
}
.widget li:hover ul {
  display:block;
}
```

thank you

Comment: Note: `animation` !== `transition`, as such `animation-delay` !== `transition-delay`

Comment: hey im not quite sure i understand. can you please explain more? thanks

Comment: @JohnB. Right now you have transitions on your elements. Then you're trying to do an animation-delay. You're delaying an animation that doesn't exist. You should be using transition-delay instead of animation-delay.